# How to change an image source after clicking a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm using an`Image` as a button. So I need the image source to be `/image1.png` by default, and when I click the Image, it will make an `if` function and change its image source to `/image2.png`. I changes the image correctly, the problem is that I have to click two times the image to change when it is first clicked.

This is what I'm using:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsPlaying = false;
        //PlayBtn.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(@"C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Project1WPF\image1.png");
    }

private void PlayBtn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPlaying == false)
        {

            PlayBtn.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(@"C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Project1WPF\image1.png");
            IsPlaying = true;
        }else if(IsPlaying == true)
        {

            PlayBtn.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(@"C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Project1WPF\image2.png");
            IsPlaying = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your problem, simply set the initial state correctly. As it stands, you have this:

1. The image starts with "image1".
2. The constructor sets `isPlaying` to `false`
3. You click the button
4. The handler runs, since `isPlaying` is `false`, the image is set to "image1" (your first block)
5. `isPlaying` is set to `true`
6. You click the button again
7. The handler runs again, since `isPlaying` is `true` the image is set to "image2".

So either flip which image is set when the current value is `false`, or set the initial value to `true` to get the behavior you describe.

As an aside, you *probably* shouldn't be doing this in the code-behind at all. The `Source` property should be bound to your View Model (through a converter) and the button's `Command` changes that source.

Comment: Ok, so I should change initial value to true? Right?

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss Probably, as long as that makes sense in context of the rest of the program.