# How to change an Image in a button on clicking the button?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an Image (image1) and a text in a button and I need to change the image 
to (image2) upon clicking. How to do so?

Comment: What have you try so far @Arso?

Comment: Yes, first try it yourself pal.

Comment: I tried the answer for this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119177/how-to-change-an-image-source-after-clicking-a-button ,but i can't use the imageConverter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Xamarin/C# way:

```
var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
button.Click += delegate { 
    button.Text = "Some New Text";

    // If your image is a Drawable
    button.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.button_background);

    // From an asset
    button.Background = Drawable.CreateFromStream(Assets.Open("button_asset.jpg"), null);

    // From an arbitrary path
    button.Background = Drawable.CreateFromPath("/sdcard/Download/downloaded_file.jpg");
};
```

#### Update:

If you are using `drawableLeft`, `drawableRight`, etc... in your layout, you can change these via `SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`:

```
button.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, Resource.Drawable.button_background, 0);
```

If you are setting multiple drawables, you can preserve and change some of them via:

```
var drawables = button.GetCompoundDrawables();
button.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawables[0], drawables[1], Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.button_background, this.Theme), drawables[3]);
```

Comment: If I've set the image (which is a Drawable) to the Right of the text, how can I change that Image to another one on clicking? @SushiHangover

Comment: @Arso Are you using an `ImageButton` or a `Button` or a ?

Comment: I'm using a Button @SushiHangover

Comment: @Arso I updated my answer but you need to fully explain in your question from where you are starting and what you are trying to achieve, i.e. Adding the button portion of your layout axml file would clarify things greatly otherwise everyone is just guessing that you are using `drawableRight` for example

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience, will do so in the future. It worked, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image);
       }
   });
```